# Optimizing playlist processing

Tags: c#, performance, xml, wpf, audio

I am trying to process an audio library file which is about 350 KB.  My application processes each song on the file gets its meta-data and displays it in a List Box.

The problem is that it takes too much time (about 1-2 mins). I need to make it faster like in the Windows Media Player. I tried to make it faster by saving meta data for each song in the library file. Now it takes about 30-50 secs.  The application works fine; no performance issues.

If I use this method then it takes 1 min to load and process:

```
    public void m3uplaylist()
    {


            try
            {
                song.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

        string fileName = null;
        FileStream fStream = null;
        StreamReader sReader = null;
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            fStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            sReader = new StreamReader(fStream);

            while ((fileName = sReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (fileName.Length > 0 && fileName.Substring(0, 1) != "#" && fileName.Substring(0, 1) != "\n") //Checks whether the first character of the line is not # or Enter
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string[] row1 = { fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("\\")) + "\\" + fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) }; //Stores the song details in string array so that it can be added to the Grid



                        for (int i = 0; i < row1.Length; i++)
                        {

                            Songss sing = new Songss(row1[i]);
                            song.Add(sing);
                            progress++;
                            workers.ReportProgress(progress, bar1);

                        }
                        TotalSongs = File.ReadAllText(filename).Length / 100;

                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                    {

                    }

                }

            }
            fStream.Close();
            sReader.Close();
        }

    }
```

---

If I use this method the library loads in about 15 seconds:

```
    public void mplplaylistload(string filename)
    {

        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            TotalSongs = File.ReadAllText(filename).Length / 100 - 500;
            string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
            // Create the query 
            var rowsFromFile = from c in XDocument.Load(
                                filename).Elements(
                                "playlist").Elements("abc123").Elements("Song")
                               select c;
            // Execute the query 
            foreach (var row in rowsFromFile)
            {
                Songss sing = new Songss(row.Element("Path").Value);

                    sing.title = row.Element("Title").Value;
                    if (GetFullInfo == true)
                    {
                        sing.album = row.Element("Album").Value;

                        sing.artist = row.Element("Artist").Value;

                        sing.length = row.Element("Length").Value;

                        sing.size = row.Element("Size").Value;

                        if (File.Exists(row.Element("Image").Value))
                        {
                            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(row.Element("Image").Value));
                            img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
                            sing.source = img;
                        }
                    }
                song.Add(sing);
                progress++;

                workers.ReportProgress(progress);
            }

        }

    }
```

---

The file from which it reads is like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <playlist>
   <abc123>
   <Song>
  <Title>9</Title>
  <Path>D:\MuziK\Music\9.mp3</Path>
  <Album>Unkown Album</Album>
  <Artist>Unknown Artist</Artist>
  <Size>2,960KB</Size>
  <Length>NA</Length>
  <Image>C:\Users\The GaMeR\AppData\Local\Macalifa\albumarts\Unkown Album\9\art.jpg</Image>
</Song>
<Song>
  <Title>Aa Bhi Ja Sanam</Title>
  <Path>D:\MuziK\Music\Aa Bhi Ja Sanam.mp3</Path>
  <Album></Album>
  <Artist></Artist>
  <Size>2,941KB</Size>
  <Length>3:08</Length>
  <Image>C:\Users\The GaMeR\AppData\Local\Macalifa\albumarts\\Aa Bhi Ja Sanam\art.jpg</Image>
</Song>
 </abc123>
```

---

What I need is to optimize the time-taken by the library to load.

**Note:** I am using background worker to load the library. Is there any better approach than this?

Comment: Can you clarify a little about your two "approaches"? From a first glance they don't seem to do the same, why exactly are they considered an alternative? And since you know one of them is 4 times faster than the other, why do you want a codereview from that slower one?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The first approach is slow, because i think it fetches meta-data for each song. The second however, is more faster because meta-data for each song is saved in the library file. I don't want codereview from slower one, i want code review of the faster one, to make it even more faster. As i have mentioned in my question, that i want it to be just like WMP, When user opens the application the library should already be loaded.....


The Don't look the same of-course.. The first one only reads the "Song Paths" but the second one reads everything.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the entire XML file, you can use XStreamingElement and xmlReader to reduce the memory foot print. As your playlist grows, large xml file will become a problem. The following MSDN link describes it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387013.aspx

Comment: Thanks!! i will look into it & inform you if it solves my problem